# Spring MVC Controllers Return Type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've seen examples where a controller returns a String (which indicates the view)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
  Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);  
  model.addAttribute("owner", owner);  
  return "displayOwner"
}
```

And I also see examples where a controller returns a "ModelAndView" object type

```
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("helloWorld");
    mav.addObject("message", "Hello World!");
    return mav;
}
```

What is the difference between the two and which should I use? Cause either way I can get my view resolved.

Comment: which version of spring mvc are we talking about?

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365833/what-are-valid-return-types-of-a-spring-mvc-controller-method/29366138#29366138

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If we are talking about MVC 3, than, both are correct. But directly returning ModelAndView is the old way, and more verbal.

If you are returning just a string (without @ResponseBody which is something else), this string is treated as view name, and spring pushes it to view resolvers - so, you dont have to worry (at least, while you are writing controllers), what type of view renderer you'll use (let it be jsp or velocity, it doesn't matter). You only propagate the `Model` instance, and returnes a hint what to do with it next. Proper `ModelAndView` object is made later internally by string.

Generally, spring 3 gives you more flexibility with arguments and return types (see [Defining @RequestMapping handler methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods) section in Spring documentaton).

Comment: In the newer MVC 3 approach (returning a `String`), how does the `Model` instance make it's way into the view? In the controller we use `model.addAttribute(..)` to add attributes but ultimately only the `String` is returned, so how does the view resolver know about the `Model` object? Thanks!

Comment: I believe its some kind of dependecy injection done by RequestMapping (i.e. model is given to you by resolver) - but to be honest, I'm not sure, as I had no contact with Spring for those past 5 years ^^

Answer (score 19):

It's the same logic but it's not the same version of spring.

The ModelAndView object is the spring 2.x way of handling model and views.
In the example you gave, the modelandview object will load the "helloWorld" view (depending on your templating engine could be helloWorld.jsp, or helloWorld.html, ...) with one data "message" in the model.

The other way is the spring 3.x way. You could have wrote exactly the same example as your helloworld.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String helloWorld(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
    return "helloWorld";
}
```

The model is automaticly populated at request.

And we can simplify this notation as the url mapping "helloWorld" is directly the view name.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void helloWorld(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
}
```

the helloWorld view will be automaticly loaded

Answer (score 6):

In Spring MVC, you should return ModelAndView if you want to render jsp page

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexView(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }
```

this function will return index.jsp when you are hitting /index.html

In addition you can return any JSON or XML object using `@ResponseBody` annotation and serializer.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getStudent.do",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Student> getStudent(@RequestParam("studentId") String id){
        List<Student> students = daoService.getStudent(id);
        return students;
    }
```

In this example you will return List as JSON in case and you have enabled Jackson serializer. In order to enable that you need to add the following to your Spring XML:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

And the Serializer itself:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
  <list>
    <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is not necessary to directly create and return MAV. Beside this, if you are using `context:annotation-config` you dont have to put serializer by hand, its done automatically if `jackson` is on the classpath.

Comment: Perfect, simple example that is very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Returning ModelAndView or a string does the same job. It resolves into a view (a jsp page) and giving a model object to be rendered in the view. If you return a string, spring internally resolves to a view using viewResolver, create a ModelAndView Object and return it. The returning of ModelAndView object is from the older version. You can do either of this based on your convenient.

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175509/which-is-better-return-modelandview-or-string-on-spring3-controller)

Also bunch of answers are pointing out to @RequestBody. Its not exactly related to your question. But keep in mind that it will convert your object based on content-type using available converters and the resuly will be part of the document body.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a template language like freemarker or velocity to create the response then you can return the `ModelAndView`.

If you want to return a json/xml or some string as the response(ex: ajax requests) then you can use the first method. I think it should be `public @ResponseBody String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model)`, you need to add a annotation called [@ResponseBody](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) to indicate that the returned value should be converted as the response text. Using `@ResponseBody` will enable you to use libraries like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [JaxB](http://jaxb.java.net/) to create json/xml responses respectively.

These returned values will be converted using the `messageConverters` registered with `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`.

Ref: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Comment: You missing the point. If you defined proper `view resolver` than returned string will be treated as name for view (jsp, template, and so on). `@ResponseBody` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @AdamJurczyk so how I can use `@ResponseBody` (i want to return JSON for ajax call) if I already have defined `view resolver`? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
  Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);  
  model.addAttribute("owner", owner);  
  return "displayOwner"
}
```

in this method the return type is String and we adding Model as a parameter so to add a value with model we will add like

```
 modelparam.addAttribute("obj",value);
```

and return to the displayowner to jsp as per view resolver

```
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("helloWorld");
    mav.addObject("message", "Hello World!");
    return mav;
}
```

in this method the return type is ModelAndView so we will return the model 
and here the mav is the object of ModelAndView so here we should add like

```
model.addObject("object","value");
```

here the viewname is returned to helloworld.jsp as per the viewResolver