# Spring controller declaration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am wondering what are the requirements for a method (or a class) to be labeled with @Controller? As for input arguments, the Spring tutorial seems to indicate that methods can sometimes take in nothing and sometimes take in a `Model` object:

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/

And this:

[Spring MVC Controllers Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383622/spring-mvc-controllers-return-type)

seems to indicate that the return type can be a String or a ModelAndView. I tried to look that up in the official documentation but couldn't find much info. I presume there must be some requirements. Any pointers?

Comment: [Supported method arguments](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-arguments), [supported method return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-return-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring Class is marked as @Controller, methods are marked as @RequestMapping handling specific request based on parameter,url path, accept header etc.

Spring MVC is highly flexible and allows you to have many return types see [spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) see "Supported method return types" section on the same page.

Also [spring-mvc-3-showcase](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/) blog