# java method not returning the correct type

Tags: java, jsp, methods, return

I have a method in a class and it is suppose to be returning a jsp file once the 'next' button is hit. but it just wipes the data from the current page and returns the current page.

this is the method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addQuestion(Model model, @RequestParam(value="question", required = true)  String theQuestion , @RequestParam(value="questionId", required = true)  Integer questionId, @RequestParam(value="category", required = true)   String category, @RequestParam(value="correctAnswer", required = true)   String correctAnswer) throws SQLException{
                ViewController viewController = new ViewController();
                viewController.createQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, correctAnswer);
                model.addAttribute("question", new Question());
                return "qFour";
        }
```

it should return qFour.jsp but it just returns addQuestion.jsp which is the page it is currently on

Comment: Is `qFour` being returned correctly?

Comment: it makes no difference what i put after return. i.e. return "qFour" return "qOne" return "qFive". the expected jsp does not appear

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7386124/3898076, your syntax is correct, So there is some other problem.

Comment: what other code will be useful for me to provide to find a solution to the problem?

Comment: first of all, try to debug your code and find out is your `addQuestion` method is getting called?

Comment: yep have run the debugger and it is not being called

Comment: can you append also the request url that the button sends to the server? Is it a post or get?

Comment: it's a post but nothing gets added to the url bar which is strange..

Comment: If you have some other url working, try if that is getting called? And check for the action attribute of another form which is properly getting submitted to the server.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: it is not solved, but your solution was syntactically correct and thus the problem/errors in my program must lie elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `ModelAndView` from method like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addQuestion(Model model, @RequestParam(value="question", required = true)  String theQuestion , @RequestParam(value="questionId", required = true)  Integer questionId, @RequestParam(value="category", required = true)   String category, @RequestParam(value="correctAnswer", required = true)   String correctAnswer) throws SQLException{
        ViewController viewController = new ViewController();
        viewController.createQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, correctAnswer);

        return return new ModelAndView("qFour", "question", new Question());
    }
```

Comment: thanks, will try now. assuming you meant just one return as well yes?

Comment: nope, it unfortunately is still doing the same thing. within the addQuestion.jsp there is a form with the action="addQuestion" which should be calling this and adding stuff to a database. perhaps the error is somewhere in there...

Comment: Which version of spring you are using?

Comment: Is your `addQuestion` method getting called?

Comment: i think spring version 3.2.7. is there an easy way to convert to 3.1.1?

Comment: im not sure if it is being called, i dont think it is because nothing is being added to the DB

Comment: Try debugging your code, but putting debug point or by sysout at the start of your method.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide your configuration files content it is hard to tell exactly what needs to be change. But i think your **addQuestion** method's return type need to be **ModelAndView** instead of **String** for your purpose. Try with this return statement:

```
return new ModelAndView("qFour.jsp");
```