# What are valid return types of a Spring MVC controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, annotations

I have not much experience in Spring MVC and I have the following about **what are  the valids return types that a controller method can return**.

So I know that the user generate an **HttpRequest** received and handled by the **DispatcherServlet** that dispatch this request to a specific controller class.

A controller class is something like this:

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping("/showAccount")
    public String show(@RequestParam("entityId") long id, Model model) {
        ...
    }

    .......................................
    .......................................
    .......................................
}
```

So I know that each method handle a specific request and that the handled request is specified by the **@RequestMapping** annotation.

I also know that the method return a **String** object that is the **logical view name** (that then is resolved by the **view resolver** to render the view)

So, at this stage, I think that a method of a controller class returns only **String** object. But I am not sure of it. Maybe a method like this can return also some different kind of objects?

Comment: there are plenty return types, you can return what you need, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383622/spring-mvc-controllers-return-type

Comment: Craig Walls' "Spring in Action" is great at explaining Spring MVC

Comment: This is very thoroughly covered in the Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are many return types are available for Handler method which is annotated by `@RequestMapping` inside the controller, like :

- ModelAndView (Class)
- Model (Interface)
- Map
- String
- void
- View
- `HttpEntity<?>` or `ResponseEntity<?>`
- `HttpHeaders`

and much more.....[See Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types)

Every return type have its specific use for example: If you are using String then it means return View Name and this view name will resolved by `ViewResolver`. If you don't want to return any view name mention return type as `void`. If you want to set view name as well as want to send some data to view use `ModelAndView` as a return type.

Please go through the documentation you will also get to know what kind of method argument you can pass in the handler method.

Answer (score 2):

You have a direct answer in the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types)

Take a special note of the

> If the method is annotated with @ResponseBody, the return type is
>   written to the response HTTP body. The return value will be converted
>   to the declared method argument type using HttpMessageConverters.

When the method is annoated with *@ResponseBody*, the return type can be any custom type, any Java pojo, that the framework will convert to an appropriate repsentation JSON, XML or the like and write back to the response body

Answer (score 1):

you could take a look at [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#getModelAndView](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java#AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.getModelAndView%28java.lang.reflect.Method%2Cjava.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Corg.springframework.ui.ExtendedModelMap%2Corg.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest%29). This method has several conditions based on the return type to choose what to do with the returned value.