# Controller return type and httpStatus best practice and production/consumption on method in REST WS

Tags: rest, web-services, spring-boot, controller, media-type

I commence in REST and I have some questions:

- What type must the controller return? Typically, I'm asking if my Rest `@Controller` must return `Item` object as it is or encapsulate it in `ResponseEntity` in order to specify http-status-code.
- What http status code to use in a GET method on a particular item ("/items/2") if the given item does  not exists: `HttpMediaStatus.OK`(200) and null return or `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT`(204) and null return ?

Second part: I saw it was possible to specify `@Produces` and `@Consumes` on WS method but what the use of that? My application and my methods work so, why specify `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`? Doesn't Spring/SpringBoot automatically convert `Item` or `ResponseEntity` into json?

Context: using Spring Boot, hibernate, REST webservice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many questions in one, I'll provide short answers with a bunch of link to relevant articles and the reference documentation.

> What type must the controller return?

Depends on your annotation and the RESTful-ness of your service. There are three annotations you can use for [controllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-controller): `@Controller`, `@RestController` and `@RepositoryRestController`.

[Controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) is the base annotation to mark your class as a controller. The return type of the controller endpoint methods can be many things, I invite you to read [this dedicated  post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29366138/5873923) to get a grasp of it.
When developing a pure-REST service, you will focus on using [RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) and [RepositoryRestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryRestController.html).
`RestController`is `Controller` + [ResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html). It binds the return value of the endpoint method to the web response body:

```
@RestController
public ItemController {

    @RequestMapping("/items/{id}")
    public Item getItem(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
         Item item = ...

         return item;
    }

}
```

With this, when you hit `http:/.../api/items/foo`, Spring does its magic, automatically converting the item to a [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) with a relevant 40X status code and some default HTTP headers.

At some point, you will need more control over the status code and headers, while still benefiting from Spring Data REST's settings. That's when you will use `RepositoryRestController` with a `ResponseEntity<Item>` as return type, see the [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) the Spring Data REST reference.

> What http status code to use in a GET method on a particular item if the given item does not exists?

Bluntly said: use [HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#NOT_FOUND). You're looking for a resource that does not exist, there's something wrong.

That being said, it is completely up to you to decide how to handle missing resources in your project. If your workflow justifies it, a missing resource could be something completely acceptable that indeed returns a 20X response, though you may expect users of your API to get confused if you haven't warned them or provided some documentation (we are creatures of habits and conventions). But I'd still start with a 404 status code.

> (...) @Produces and @Consumes on WS method but what the use of that? My application and my methods work so, why specify MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE? Doesn't Spring/SpringBoot automatically convert Item or ResponseEntity into json?

`@Consumes` and `@Produces` are respectively matched against `content-type` and `accept` headers from the request. It's a mean of restricting the input accepted and the output provided by your endpoint method.

Since we're talking about a REST service, communications between clients of the API and the service are expected to be JSON-formatted. Thanks to Spring HATEOAS, the answer are actually formatted with the `application/hal+json` content-type.
In that scenario, you can indeed not bother with those two annotations. You will need them if you develop a service that accepts different content-types (application/text, application/json, application/xml...) and provides, for instance, HTML views to users of your website and JSON or XML response to automated clients of your service.

For real life examples:

- Facebook provides the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) for applications to read to/write from its graph, while users happily (?) surf on web pages
- Google does the same with the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your very complete answer, I will meditate on all this content but I already think to stay on `@RestController` if it magically use standard HttpStatus code according to returned content as you said (even if I have to really understand concretes differences with `@RepositoryRestController` I didn't know).

Comment: And, no link with previous question but still in transferring data subject : is there any recommandation about using primitive or object type when transferring data ? Does my Item id must be Long or long or just according to my needs ?

Comment: You should try out both annotations and you will quickly see the differences (and probably have more questions).

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, in request parameters, use wrapper types. They are nullable, which is handy for optional request parameters. They are Objects, so can be used in Collections and therefore any implementation of a List, which has an extremely useful [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). The main drawback is that they add an overhead by being wrappers around primitive types. Unless you handle a very large lot of data in your requests, that shouldn't be critical performance-wise. This is worth a separate question that deserves a far more elaborate answer.

Comment: Ok, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824840/when-to-use-restcontroller-vs-repositoryrestresource), `@RepositoryRestController` should allow to work "without service layer" because with logic needed, CRUDRepo can be instantly used.
Continuing with `@RestController`, do you know how to implements PATCH method (partial update), I don't see how to do without getting existing item and setting properties manually then saving with CRUDRepositoey ?

Comment: Hummm, not so magic, it returns 200 when return result is null, but resolved adding `HttpServletResponse response` in parameter and setting response code to custom code :

`@GetMapping(path = "/{itemNum}")`

`public ItemDTO retrieveItem(@PathVariable Long itemNum, HttpServletResponse response) {`


`        ItemDTO item = itemService.retrieveItem(itemNum);`


`        if(item == null) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return item;`


    `}`

Comment: Do you really to implement PATCH by hand? As long as you extend A CrudRepository (or any descendant) Spring Data REST automatically provides you with RESTful endpoints for GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE/OPTIONS/HEAD requests. It is doable, but PATCH may be a bit tricky. This is worth a separate question (which has already been asked here and there, you should already be able to find useful answers on StackOverflow).

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. You would better create a new question and state your problem and code sample. You will get better visibility and answers :)