# SpringMVC @RequestMapping return String ModelAndView

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two methods for spring MVC `@RequestMapping` return but i don't know 
how to choose 
I would like to ask the difference between the two methods???

//return ModelAndView

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginRetunModel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectModel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

// return String

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginReturnString", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectString(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: From a functional perspective there is no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M. Deinum pointed out there is no difference in what the mappings result in.

Here are related SO answers

[What are valid return types of a Spring MVC controller method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365833/what-are-valid-return-types-of-a-spring-mvc-controller-method)

[Which return type use in spring mvc in @RequestMapping method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607290/which-return-type-use-in-spring-mvc-in-requestmapping-method?rq=1)

From the  [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types):

> String
>
> A view name to be resolved with ViewResolver's and used together with
> the implicit model — determined through command objects and
> @ModelAttribute methods. The handler method may also programmatically
> enrich the model by declaring a Model argument (see above).
>
> ModelAndView object
>
> The view and model attributes to use, and optionally a response
> status.

Basically the String return type is used to declare the name of the view to be displayed and ModelAndView gives the possibility to additionally add model attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I can give one difference though as your class is missing

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginReturnString", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectString(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
      return "login";
    }
```

will return **login.jsp** or other extension based on your view resolved.

but

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginReturnString", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectString(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
      return "login";
    }
```

will return a **String "login"**. @RestController made the difference

Comment: sorry ,  because I use @Controller but I thought it was working "@RequestMapping"