How do we decide whether we need to use ModelAndView or String in the method of Controller of Spring?
I have seen somewhere we use ModelAndView or Model or String in the method of Controller - how do we actually decide what's need to be used ?
I am just confused after reading multiple resources. Can someone explain me in detail? How do we decide whether we need to use ModelAndView or String in the method of Controller of Spring?

Well, String is letting you to pass a static view name, but for passing some data to the view you need a Model. And if you need a dynamic view name, you switch to ModelAndView. So, always start from the most simple solution, but if it's not enough - try more complicated.

You might find the following helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7383622/28908340
