# When to use ModelAndView vs Model in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This might sound dumb to the `Spring` experts, but I have to ask:
How do you decide on when to use `ModelAndView` and when to use `Model`?

After all I have researched the best answer I have found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175509/which-is-better-return-modelandview-or-string-on-spring3-controller). It has mentioned that the `ModelAndView` is an old way and the `Model` with a `String` returned is a new way in `Spring`.

My question is shall we deprecate the old `ModelAndView` now that we have `Model` in hand? Or is there any cases that you need to use `ModelAndView` for it?

Also, does anyone know why the have to change `ModelAndView` to `Model` and `String` value as `View`, and what are the benefits?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I always use the approach where controller methods return `ModelAndView`. Simply because it tends to make the controller methods a little more terse. The method parameters are now strictly `input` parameters. And all `output` related data is contained in the object returned from the method.

The `ModelAndView` style seems to resonate with people who don't like updating input parameters to a method. Sticking to the belief that this would constitute a side effect, a dangerous pattern because you cannot reliably predict what the method is going to do - It could return data in the returned object, or it could have updated anything in any of the input arguments.

So some people will still continue to prefer `ModelAndView`.

The new style with `Model` as method parameter and returned string as view name. Seems to have come from a slightly different design approach. Here the model objects are considered to be sort of events or items that are passed to multiple handlers, before being returned to the view where they are rendered. It reminds me how events are handled in the AWT / Swing world. This model is more coherent with the approach where multiple handlers could build on top of the `Model` objects, till it reaches a view.

So at the end of the day, there does not seem to be a definite reason to criticise or promote either approach. You should use the style that feels more consistent to your overall design philosophy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked thanks :)

Here is my code: 

`@RequestMapping(value = "STB1/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView homeAction() {
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("STB1/home");
  return mav; // renders the // /<packagename>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/STB1/home.jsp
 }`

Answer (score 17):

One difference I can spot is with ModelAndView object you can set a direct reference to a view object:

```
ModelAndView mav = ...
mav.setView(myView);
```

Whereas if you use Model and String, you need a view resolver to resolve the view name into an actual view

```
public String myHandler(...) {
   return "myviewname"; // has to have a resolver from "myviewname" into an actual view
}
```

Comment: Though I agree with this, I still prefer to have the View Resolvers resolve the page to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In SEO perspective, We can use ModelAndView to apply the 301 redirection if we have any requirements for that, We cannot achieve this using Model.