# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I get this error when accessing `http://api:8080/users` which 404's and I get this error in my console:

> Sep 23, 2014 5:57:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>       WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/users] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

When I access `http://localhost:8080/api/users` I get a 404 in my browser but no error in my console

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.api"/>
</beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    ">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.api"/>      
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Users.java:

```
package com.api;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RequestMapping("/users")
public class Users {
     @Autowired
     public Users() {

     }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getUser() {
        System.out.println("\nhere\n");
    }
}
```

If anyone has any clue I'd greatly appreciate it. I've looked up several questions with the same error as I'm getting but common solution was to add     which I have already, so I'm not sure what else to do. Thanks.

EDIT: I've just updated all the code to what the latest reference doc, and I still get the same error.
EDIT: Update to show my current state of files.

Comment: Read the Spring Reference Documentation, you are mixing the old configuration together with the new configuration about Spring MVC. Your code is wrong.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: I've updated my question with the latest code from the reference documentation and I still get the same error.

Comment: Now your configuration *is* correct. The URL `http://api:8080/` has no sense, the URL to test **must be** `http://localhost:8080/CONTEXTROOT/users` where `CONTEXTROOT` is available in your project selected `Right Click -> Properties -> Web Project Settings`. If your project is already deployed in Tomcat, then  the URL must be `http://localhost:8080/projectname/users`

Comment: I've done that but I still get a 404, but I get no error in my console.

Comment: Update your first post, share the complete error stack trace. I need more details

Comment: Updated, the full stack trace is shown at the top, just those two lines are all I get

Comment: If is only that, could you check your Tomcat's `log` directory? There should appear more details. check the log files, since there are many according of their roles.

Comment: There's nothing in catalina.out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your web.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and dispatch-servlet.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.api"/>
</beans>
```

You don't need applicationContext.xml for your code to run

Comment: I tried that but I had to add:             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd to get it working, but I still get the same error

Comment: In your Java class Users, you need to have the @Controller annotation on the class(you had it before editing).

Comment: I tried it with and without the @Controller, either work

Comment: Are you getting noHandlerFound exception or 404 error? If it's 404, that's because your controller does not return any object or model. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175509/which-is-better-return-modelandview-or-string-on-spring3-controller

Comment: I get noHandlerFound in my eclipse console but 404 in the browser

Comment: The @Autowired annotation causes `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public com.api.Users()`, that needs to be removed. But still cannot reproduce noHandlerFound error.

Comment: it's been so long time ago, cannot recall the details now.

Answer (score 8):

After spending whole day i got to know the solution. 
When you create maven project, by default it doesn't create 'java' folder under 'javaResource/src/main', which is required to get the controller path.

Make sure you create java folder first inside 'javaResource/src/main', then create your package and controller.

Screenshot attached for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I faced the same problem, now you helped me to solve.

Comment: Thanks. I created the class and it ended up in the resources folder.

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake is this
Make sure the group id in pom.xml is the parent of that mentioned in

```
    </context:component-scan>
```

For Example
If  Group `Id-com.cavesofprogramming.spring.web` then

```
    <context:component-scan base- package="com.cavesofprogramming.spring.web.controllers">
```

The effect is that the controller is not found in the maven build and 
        as a result the mapping not done to the correct jsp.

Comment: Please format your code properly so the OP can determine what are comments and what is code.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the following lines in your spring-context.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

Note: property prefix and suffix need to modify based on your application like  .jsp if you are using jsp files.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got around this and what I was doing wrong.

On creating a maven project with web archetype we do not have the java directory under main. You will have to create it manually and add a directory under it. This directory is the base-package that the servlet.xml wants.

servlet.xml and the location of the base-package image attached for reference

[View image for viewing the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/573DF.png)

Answer (score 1):

in maven ,'java' folder was not created . I created as src/main/java and this issue was resolved .

it is suggested by jyot also in this post .
[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005483/org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet-nohandlerfound/59751830#59751830)

Answer (score 0):

Cause - Main reason behind this issue is servlet.xml file is not able to find the proper controller that could redirect your request.

Solution - Ensure few things:

1. In servlet.xml file your base-package should point to the correct path where the controller class resides.
2. @Controller should be mentioned over the controller class.
3. In controller class @RequestMapping value should be as same as the web.xml url-pattern parameter.
4. In controller class, ModelAndView returns .jsp page should be at the same path which is pointing in the servlet.xml prefix value of ViewResolver.

Answer (score 0):

I Have also faced the same problem 
 `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound`

I am hitting different url in postman to solve this problem just check your postman which URL you hitting

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the `servlet.xml` file and solved the problem:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.YOURHOST" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue while copying from one project to another. I missed to add the index.jsp

Adding this resolved my issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and very basic mistake i did was:

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

wrong package name as it was "com.test" and i had written "com.controller"..

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32174977)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have given the wrong address for the jsp page for which mapping have been done.

What I have given-

name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views"

What it should actually be-

name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"

Only a slight difference of slash(/) cause the error.

Ensure that all the changes you have made should be saved.