# Spring MVC Controller working but not creating the specified response URL ,It is creating the url from request mapping string

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am studying spring MVC based webapps. So I created a project in spring mvc and I have chosen eclipse IDE.Apache tomcat 8 server and jre1.8 the version of spring package is 4.2.5. In my project I created the login and that worked fine after login the I redirected the page to another jsp called 'branchinsert.jsp' that placed in an another folder (login.jsp and branchinsert.jsp are from different folders). In Branchinsert.jsp Spring MVC Controller is working but not create the specified response URL ,It is creating the url from request mapping string that means if I am giving the pattern like bellow mentioned,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/branchsubmitinsert.travel", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitBranchInsert(@ModelAttribute BranchModel branchModel){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/branch/branchinsert");

    return modelAndView;

}
```

showing 404 error for the url  /ProjectName/modules/branch/branchsubmitinsert.jsp

Actually the url i expected is /branch/branchinsert.jsp(this is what usually happens) but here created /branch/branchsubmitinsert.jsp url. why????

this is my code

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
 version="3.0">
<display-name>CalicutTravels</display-name>
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener><listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

      <context:component-scan base-package="com.classes.controller">
          <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"  
                expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
      </context:component-scan>

  </beans>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.classes.controller">
  </context:component-scan>
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/modules/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- declare beans -->

      <bean id="userDaoImplementation" 
       class="com.classes.dao.login.UserDaoImplementation" />
      <bean id="userServiceImplementation"

      class="com.classes.service.login.UserServiceImplementation" />

   <!-- declare datasource bean "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port
   /dbname","username", "password");-->
  <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
   /db_enterpricer_travel" />
   <property name="username" value="vishnu" />
   <property name="password" value="root" />
  </bean>

  </beans>
```

branchinsert.jsp's form field

```
 <form action='branchsubmitinsert.travel' id='brach_submit' method='post' >
            <fieldset class="well the-fieldset">
                <legend class="the-legend">  INSERT </legend>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th> Branch Name :</th>
                            <td> <input type="text" name='branchName' id='branchName' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value='INSERT' onclick='return validateBranchInsert()'/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


             </fieldset>
        </form>
```

The controller class BranchController.java

```
 package com.classes.controller.branch;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

 import com.classes.service.branch.BranchModel;


 /**
 * @author vishnu
 *
 */

 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/branch")
 public class BranchController {

 @RequestMapping(value="/branchinsert.travel", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getBranchInsert(){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/branch/branchinsert");
    return modelAndView;

 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/branchupdate.travel", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getBranchUpdate(){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/branch/branchupdate");
    return modelAndView;

 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/branchshow.travel", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getBranchShow(){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/branch/branchshow");
    return modelAndView;

 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/branchdelete.travel", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getBranchDelete(){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/branch/branchdelete");
    return modelAndView;

 }

@RequestMapping(value="/branchsubmitinsert.travel",
method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitBranchInsert(@ModelAttribute BranchModel 
branchModel){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/branch/branchinsert");
    modelAndView.addObject("branch",branchModel);
    return modelAndView;

}

}
```

Comment: module named folder having the jsp file containing folders (login,branch..etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the return type of method submitBranchInsert as String as follows

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/branchsubmitinsert.travel", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitBranchInsert(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute BranchModel branchModel){

    //ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/branch/branchinsert");
    //modelAndView.addObject("branch",branchModel);
    //return modelAndView;
    model.addAttribute("branch", branchModel);
    return "/branch/branchinsert";

}
```

now its ok but why i can't use ModelAndView here instead of Model in String ,
may be my sound dumb to the experts in Spring MVC.
I just want to know when should use ModelAndView instead of  Model in String?
I don't want to ask this question as separately that is why I am asking this with my answer itself.
anybody can help me?

Comment: If you need response a client with some data for rendering page not only a page, you should use `ModelAndView `.

Comment: Ok..got it but look i can give data in 'String in model' concept also.. I am passing the object with response please look my answer, here the problem that I found is while I am using ModelAndView as a return type, the view resolver creating branchsubmit.jsp and in other case it is creating branchinsert,jsp

Comment: OK, U R right, please take a look of [Which is better, return “ModelAndView” or “String” on spring3 controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175509/which-is-better-return-modelandview-or-string-on-spring3-controller)

Comment: Don't post a question as an answer, if you have another question ask a new question or extend your original question.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok here after i will not.. do like this, I was hurry so that i put like this.

Comment: @Reno thank you very much for gave me a reference link

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned modules folder in the prefix of viewResolver it is working like that..

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/modules/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Which means return `"branch/branchInsert"` will find jsp in `/modules/branch/branchInsert.jsp`.

If you use just string to return means it's just an path from the jsp where you are sending the requset.So for that **`viewResolver`** wont add prefix folder.

But if you use `ModelAndView` the viewResolver will add the prefix and suffix.

Comment: yeah,.. now it is runninf according to my logic. But why it is generating branchsubmitinsert.jsp while am using ModelAndView as a return type. So there is some difference between String in model and ModelAndView that is what I am looking for.., Thank you for your response :-)

Comment: Updated answer..if you want to check move branchsubmitInsert.jsp to some other folder and test by giving branch/branchinsert